# Linux Terminal user authentication using php

Tags: php, linux

How to check username and password of linux terminal using php?

My requirement is that, command prompt output display in webpage. Already i have write this code.My question is that How to check terminal user using php ?.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [expect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.expect.php)?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim No i want to compare username and password with Terminal username and password

Comment: Do you want a website to grant users control of a machine, using PHP? This seems like a really big security risk... Why not just use SSH?

Comment: This is use for our company internal testing not worldwide.Can anyone tell me it is possible or not?

Comment: I'm not clear what you want to do. If you want to somehow have your program integrate with the system auth. system, consider using [this](http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM).

Comment: Ok I have give example of my requirement. 
I have one testing linux terminal user, this user can perform any task on terminal after loging.I have use this user name and password in php page compare with terminal user and password for authentication.

Comment: You can either use the PAM thing I've linked to above or if you're using apache, can authenticate against the passwd file directly. This is a [bad idea](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FAQ#Can_I_use_my_.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-passwd_file_for_Web_page_authentication.3F).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fullfill my requirement using [posix_getpwnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwnam.php) php function.